# SELECT with many LEFT JOINs runs very slowly

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I would like some advice on how I could **optimize the performance** of a query that is stored in a procedure.

Previously, it took **20 minutes** and now we can get it in **13 minutes**. But it's still a long time.

I've checked the indexes several times, updated the statistics too and got the 13 minutes running.

I also tried to replace the logic of `LEFT JOIN` with `OUTER APPLY` but performance deteriorated.

Strangely, when I removed the `[ShowToUser] = 1` filter in the `WHERE` clause, in SSMS the query was very fast (all records have a value of 1), so I commented this line of code and I removed the indexes with this column, as I thought it unnecessary. But when processing via application, the performance was even worse!

```
SELECT COUNT([Id]) AS [Events],
    [ClientId],
    [PersonId],
    [FullName],
    [SuperiorId],
    [Manager],
    [ClientPhoneNumberId],
    [PhoneNumber],
    [Departament],
    [CostCenter],
    [CostCenterCode],
    [TelecomUserInitialDate],
    [TelecomUserEndDate],
    [TelecomUserId],
    [PhoneCompanyId],
    [PhoneCompanyName],
    (SUM([UserCost]) / COUNT(DISTINCT [ReferenceMonth])) AS [AverageCostMonth],
    MAX([ReferenceMonth]) AS [ReferenceMonth],
    CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN [ReferenceMonth] = @referenceMonthEnd
                    THEN [UserCost]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS [CostSumLastReference],
    Meta,
    ServicesValue,
    RegisteredArea,
    CASE 
        WHEN ServicesValue > 0
            THEN (
                    ServicesValue - CAST(SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN [ReferenceMonth] = @referenceMonthEnd
                                    THEN [UserCost]
                                ELSE 0
                                END) AS DECIMAL(18, 4))
                    ) * 100 / ServicesValue
        ELSE 0
        END AS ServicesPercent,
    CASE 
        WHEN Meta > 0
            THEN (
                    Meta - CAST(SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN [ReferenceMonth] = @referenceMonthEnd
                                    THEN [UserCost]
                                ELSE 0
                                END) AS DECIMAL(18, 4))
                    ) * 100 / Meta
        ELSE 0
        END AS MetaPercent
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t].[Id],
        [c].[Id] AS [ClientId],
        [p2].[Id] AS [PersonId],
        [p2].[FullName],
        [p2].[SuperiorId],
        [mg].[Fullname] AS [Manager],
        [cn].[Id] AS [ClientPhoneNumberId],
        [n].[Number] AS [PhoneNumber],
        [dp].[Name] AS [Departament],
        [tcc].[Name] AS [CostCenter],
        [tcc].[Code] AS [CostCenterCode],
        [tu].[InitialDate] AS [TelecomUserInitialDate],
        [tu].[EndDate] AS [TelecomUserEndDate],
        [a].[ReferenceMonth] AS [ReferenceMonth],
        [tu].[Id] AS [TelecomUserId],
        tu.goal AS Meta,
        tu.ServicesValue,
        tu.RegisteredArea,
        CASE 
            WHEN @phoneCompanyId IS NOT NULL
                THEN [cn].[PhoneCompanyId]
            ELSE NULL
            END AS [PhoneCompanyId],
        [cp].[TradingName] [PhoneCompanyName],
        CAST([t].[UserCost] AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS [UserCost]
    FROM [telecom].[CallDetailRecord] AS [t]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[TelecomBill] AS [a]
        ON [a].[Id] = [t].[TelecomBillId]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[TelecomBillAccount] AS [tba]
        ON [tba].[Id] = [a].[TelecomBillAccountId]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[TelecomBillAccountContract] AS [tbacon]
        ON [tbacon].[TelecomBillAccountId] = [tba].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [doc].[PersonContract] AS [pcontr]
        ON [pcontr].[Id] = [tbacon].[ContractId]
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Person] AS [p]
        ON [p].[Id] = [pcontr].[ContractorId]
    LEFT JOIN [customer].[Client] AS [c]
        ON [c].[PersonId] = [p].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[PhoneNumber] AS [n]
        ON [n].[Id] = [t].[PhoneNumberId]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[ClientPhoneNumber] AS [cn]
        ON [cn].[PhoneNumberId] = [n].[Id]
            AND [cn].[ClientId] = [c].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[TelecomUser] AS [tu]
        ON [tu].[ClientPhoneNumberId] = [cn].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Person] AS [cp]
        ON [cp].Id = [cn].[PhoneCompanyId]
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Person] AS [p2]
        ON [p2].[Id] = [tu].[PersonId]
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Person] AS [mg]
        ON [mg].[Id] = [p2].[SuperiorId]
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Departament] AS [dp]
        ON [dp].[Id] = [cn].[DepartamentId]
    LEFT JOIN [accounting].[CostCenter] AS [cc]
        ON [cc].[Id] = [dp].[CostCenterId]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[TelecomUserCostCenter] AS [tuc]
        ON [tuc].[TelecomUserId] = [tu].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [accounting].[CostCenter] AS [tcc]
        ON [tcc].[Id] = [tuc].[CostCenterId]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[PhoneNumber] AS [n1]
        ON [n1].[Id] = [t].[CalledPhoneNumberId]
    WHERE (
            [t].[CallDate] BETWEEN [tu].[InitialDate]
                AND (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN [tu].[EndDate] IS NULL
                                THEN getdate()
                            ELSE [tu].[EndDate]
                            END
                        )
            OR [t].[CallDate] IS NULL
            )
        AND [ShowToUser] = 1
        AND [c].[Id] = @clientId
        AND [p2].[SuperiorId] = @superiorId
        AND [cn].[PhoneCompanyId] = ISNULL(@phoneCompanyId, [cn].[PhoneCompanyId])
        AND (
            ISNULL([cn].[DepartamentId], 0) = ISNULL(@departamentId, 0)
            OR [cn].[DepartamentId] = ISNULL(@departamentId, [cn].[DepartamentId])
            )
        AND [a].[ReferenceMonth] BETWEEN @referenceMonthInitial
            AND @referenceMonthEnd
    ) AS tb
GROUP BY [ClientId],
    [PersonId],
    [FullName],
    [Manager],
    [ClientPhoneNumberId],
    [PhoneNumber],
    [Departament],
    [CostCenter],
    [CostCenterCode],
    [TelecomUserInitialDate],
    [TelecomUserEndDate],
    [SuperiorId],
    [TelecomUserId],
    [PhoneCompanyId],
    [PhoneCompanyName],
    Meta,
    ServicesValue,
    RegisteredArea
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good work updating statistics as well as checking indexes.

With that monster, you need to simplify and reduce the load and complexity as early as possible.

- Anything in your `WHERE` clause that can be put into a `JOIN` safely should be, unless you measure a performance degradation.

  - such as an equality to a parameter!
  - this lets SQL eliminate rows as early as possible
- Create #temp tables for subsets of those tables - a few joined together at a time

  - And put useful unique clustered indexes on those #temp tables!
  - Apply your filtering as early as possible, getting only the rows you need
  - Get ONLY the columns you need, plus enough for uniqueness (to prevent bad data)
  - As an example, `CREATE TABLE #cnAndSubset (cols you need)`, and then `INSERT` into it every row you need from `cn` and every table that joins ONLY on `cn`. Index that #temp table and then replace the existing many joins in the query with one join to the #temp table.  Repeat with reasonable sets until performance levels off.
- Figure out WHY you have the `DISTINCT` and that massive `GROUP BY`

  - Most common cause: joins that fail to isolate only the rows required correctly
  - on that `GROUP BY` - if Manager is ALWAYS the same for a given PersonId, and you're already grouping on PersonID, take the `MAX(Manager)` or `MIN(Manager)`, don't group by it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do all the already-mentioned tricks in the other answers, but also clean up that inner query to the following. (there was some crazy filter logic overcomplications)

```
    ...
    FROM [telecom].[CallDetailRecord] AS [t]
    JOIN [telecom].[TelecomBill] AS [a] ON [a].[Id] = [t].[TelecomBillId]
        AND [a].[ReferenceMonth] BETWEEN @referenceMonthInitial
            AND @referenceMonthEnd
    JOIN [telecom].[TelecomBillAccount] AS [tba] ON [tba].[Id] = [a].[TelecomBillAccountId]
    JOIN [telecom].[TelecomBillAccountContract] AS [tbacon] ON [tbacon].[TelecomBillAccountId] = [tba].[Id]
    JOIN [doc].[PersonContract] AS [pcontr] ON [pcontr].[Id] = [tbacon].[ContractId]
    JOIN [people].[Person] AS [p] ON [p].[Id] = [pcontr].[ContractorId]
    JOIN [customer].[Client] AS [c] ON [c].[PersonId] = [p].[Id]
        AND [c].[Id] = @clientId
    JOIN [telecom].[PhoneNumber] AS [n] ON [n].[Id] = [t].[PhoneNumberId]
    JOIN [telecom].[ClientPhoneNumber] AS [cn] ON [cn].[PhoneNumberId] = [n].[Id]
        AND [cn].[ClientId] = [c].[Id]
    JOIN [telecom].[TelecomUser] AS [tu] ON [tu].[ClientPhoneNumberId] = [cn].[Id]
    JOIN [people].[Person] AS [p2] ON [p2].[Id] = [tu].[PersonId]
        AND [p2].[SuperiorId] = @superiorId
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Person] AS [cp]
        ON [cp].Id = [cn].[PhoneCompanyId]
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Person] AS [mg]
        ON [mg].[Id] = [p2].[SuperiorId]
    LEFT JOIN [people].[Departament] AS [dp]
        ON [dp].[Id] = [cn].[DepartamentId]
    LEFT JOIN [accounting].[CostCenter] AS [cc]
        ON [cc].[Id] = [dp].[CostCenterId]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[TelecomUserCostCenter] AS [tuc]
        ON [tuc].[TelecomUserId] = [tu].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [accounting].[CostCenter] AS [tcc]
        ON [tcc].[Id] = [tuc].[CostCenterId]
    LEFT JOIN [telecom].[PhoneNumber] AS [n1]
        ON [n1].[Id] = [t].[CalledPhoneNumberId]
    WHERE (
            [t].[CallDate] BETWEEN [tu].[InitialDate]
                AND ISNULL([tu].[EndDate], getdate())
            OR [t].[CallDate] IS NULL
            )
        AND [ShowToUser] = 1
        AND (@phoneCompanyId IS NULL OR [cn].[PhoneCompanyId] = @phoneCompanyId)
        AND (@departamentId IS NULL OR [cn].[DepartamentId] = @departamentId)
    ) AS tb
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately rewriting the query, slowed it down though I believe your idea makes more sense.

This server is in a `Standard 2016` version, I thought about using the `In-Memory OLTP` feature, is this a good idea?

Comment: From the MS webpage on IM OLTP: "In-Memory OLTP can significantly improve the performance of **transaction processing, data ingestion/load, and transient data** scenarios." You are doing **reporting** (aka. just a SELECT) so I don't think it will help in this case.